# Use differentials to approximate the arc length of the graph of the equation from P to Q

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Use differentials to approximate the arc length of the graph of the equation from $P$ to $Q$. (Round your answer to four decimal places.)
$$y = \sqrt x+ 5;\quad    P(4, 7), Q(4.1, 7.025)$$

so I know that the integral to find arc length is $\sqrt{1+(f'(x)^2)}$ but I am having trouble with this one for some reason. I said that the derivative was $1/2x^{1/2}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For $x=4$ the value of the derivative is $y'(4)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt4}=\frac{1}{4}$

Since the points P anQ are very close one to the other, the length of the arc is very close to the corresponding length on the tangent. So an approximate of the length is :
$$\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}\:(4.1-4)\simeq 0.10307764$$

The exact analytical method is more complicated :

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}\right)^2}\:dx=\left[x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4x}} -\frac{1}{8}\ln\left( 1+2x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4x}} \right)\right]_{x=x_1}^{x=x_2}$$

$$\int_{4}^{4.1}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}\right)^2}\:dx\simeq 0.10304036 $$